# Modified variable won't display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Skate Dice program that will pick a random number(s) and display the results together.The problem is that the result of the random number will not show, instead it is `undefined`. Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azJmZL)

```
function rolldie1() {
  Math.random(); 
}

if (rolldie1 < 0.99) {
  var answer1 = "Ollie";
}

function show1() {
  alert (answer1);
}
```

Comment: Please include the link.

Comment: OMFG trying to do anything on this site is ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

A function needs to return a value, and when calling it you need to use `()`

So it should be

```
function rolldie1()
{
 return Math.random(); 
}
if (rolldie1() < 0.99)
  {
var answer1 = "Ollie";
  }
function show1()
{
  alert (answer1);
}
```

---

Unless you wanted to store this in a variable so you can do multiple checks

```
var rolldie1 = Math.random(),
    answer1; 

if (rolldie1 < 0.99)
  {
    answer1 = "Ollie";
  }
function show1()
{
  alert (answer1);
}
```